# Why is Crowley of red color in cloud form while other demons are black clouds in Supernatural?

Tags: character, supernatural

All the demons in *Supernatural*, when they exit their human vessels, are in form of a black smoke cloud.

However, in Season 9 Episode 10, Crowley enters into Sam's body to ask him to expel the Gadreel. Here he is seen moving from his current body to Sam's body in form of a red color cloud. Why is his color different from other demons?

What's different about him, even strong demons like Abadon are in black cloud form?

Comment: He's the King of Hell, which sort of sets him apart from other demons. I don't know if an actual explanation has ever been given though.

Comment: I also thought of that , but that moment he was in kind of fight with Abadon to remain king of Hell. Not sure if there is any other specific power can be get by being King.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think after **Sam Tries to Humanize him by injecting him with Purified human blood, his smoke form has turned to Red**. I like Crowley, he is an interesting character and now has an emotional side to him as well. He is my favorite character now.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, Crowley is a demon. But to be more precise: His 'demon species' is [Crossroad Demon](https://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Crossroad_Demon) and all Crossroad Demons have red eyes. I'm not sure if their smoke is also red, but this could be an explanation.

Comment: This is 100% correct.  Other crossroads demons have been seen flashing red eyes throughout the series.  I'm not sure that we've ever seen another crossroads demon smoke out before, though.

Comment: In the latest episode "Celebrating the Life of Asa Fox" - the crossroads demon has red eyes but black smoke.

Comment: The german episodes are at S11E08 so i am not uptodate... badly

Comment: Other crossroads demons have been seen with black smoke, I think it was in 2x08 Crossroad Blues. It might be because he was once the King of the Crossroad Demons, but I don't think it's ever been explained.

Answer (score -1):

It could be because he was the King if the Crossroads before he was ever the king of Hell, maybe he was already a dangerously powerful demon and combined with the red eyes of the Crossroad Demons it gave him Red smoke

Answer (score -2):

It's not because of Sam's purified blood, because in Season 8 Episode 2, when Crowley gets out of Mrs Tran. However, Sam only injected his purified blood to Crowley at the end of Season 8, so his smoke is always red. My theory is his smoke is red because he holds the Demon Tablet, just like how Castiel got freed from Naomi's influence when he touched the Angel Tablet.

Comment: Also, It is Not because He is a Crossroad Demon, Not Because Crossroad demons have Red Eyes, Their Smoke is Red, Their Smoke is Black, As seen when Dean Trapped a Crossroad demon to Trash the Contract of a Man, and the Demon said "If you exorcise me, He is the first one I will kill when i got out", Then Dean let the Demon out, and it Escape with a BLACK smoke, If you're going with the Theory of Eye color is smoke color, You should See Azazal's Smoke is Yellow, and Lilith and Alastair's smoke is White, Friggin idjits

Comment: Crowley was king of the crossroads then king of hell. It has nothing to do with the demon tablet because he had half of it then lost it all. His smoke is red because he is king of the crossroads and holds the contract to every deal/ soul collection. Then he became king of hell making him even more powerful. Idjits is a perfect word, Crade.